# Series Question: $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n^2}{(4n^2-1)^3}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

How to compute the following series:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n^2}{(4n^2-1)^3}$$

I tried to use partial fraction

$$\begin{align}\frac{n^2}{(4n^2-1)^3}&=\frac{1}{64(2n+1)}-\frac{1}{64(2n-1)}+\frac{1}{64(2n+1)^2}+\frac{1}{64(2n-1)^2}\\&-\frac{1}{32(2n+1)^3}+\frac{1}{32(2n-1)^3}\end{align}$$

I can compute

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left[\frac{1}{64(2n+1)}-\frac{1}{64(2n-1)}\right]=-\frac{1}{64}$$

using telescoping series, but I cannot compute the rest. I believe there's a better way than this. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you need an exact solution or an order/approximation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From where you left off...:

$\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{1}{32}\cdot \left(\dfrac{1}{(2n-1)^3} - \dfrac{1}{(2n+1)^3}\right) = \dfrac{1}{32}\cdot \left(1 - \dfrac{1}{3^3} + \dfrac{1}{3^3} - \dfrac{1}{5^3} + ... \right) = \dfrac{1}{32}$, and

$\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{1}{64}\cdot \left(\dfrac{1}{(2n-1)^2} + \dfrac{1}{(2n+1)^2}\right) = \dfrac{1}{32}\cdot \displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{1}{(2n-1)^2} - \dfrac{1}{64} = \dfrac{1}{32}\cdot \dfrac{\pi^2}{8} - \dfrac{1}{64}$.

Thus adding these values and your partial answer to complete the calculation.

Comment: Thanks. I like your answer. :)

Answer (score 5):

Note that:
$$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }{\frac {{n}^{2}}{ \left( 4\,{n}^{2}-1 \right) ^{3
}}}=\frac{1}{4}\,\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{1}{\left( 4\,{n}^{2}-1 \right)^3 }+
 \frac{1}{\left( 4\,{n}^{2}-1 \right)^2 }\tag{1}$$
then note that:
$$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }  \frac{1}{\left( {n}^{2}-{x}^{2} \right)}=\frac{1}{2x^2}-\frac{1}{2}\,{\frac {\pi \,\cot \left( \pi \,x \right) }{x}}\tag{2}$$
insert $(2)$ into the differential equation:
$$ \left( {\frac {d^{2}}{d{x}^{2}}}f \left( x \right)  \right) a+
 \left( {\frac {d}{dx}}f \left( x \right)  \right) b \tag{3}$$
and evaluate $(3)$ at $x=1/2$ to get:
$$\frac{1}{4}\,\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }{\frac {a\,512}{ \left( 4\,{n}^{2}-1
 \right) ^{3}}}+{\frac {128\,a+64\,b}{ \left( 4\,{n}^{2}-1 \right) ^{2
}}}=a \left( 48-4\,{\pi }^{2} \right) +b \left( -8+{\pi }^{2} \right)\tag{4} $$
then let:
$$a=\frac{1}{512},\quad b=\frac{3}{256} \tag{5} $$ 
to get:

> $$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }{\frac {{n}^{2}}{ \left( 4\,{n}^{2}-1 \right) ^{3
> }}}=\frac{1}{4}\,\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{1}{\left( 4\,{n}^{2}-1 \right)^3 }+
>  \frac{1}{\left( 4\,{n}^{2}-1 \right)^2 }={\frac {1}{256}}\,{\pi }^{2} \tag{6} $$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. :)

Answer (score 3):

**HINT**:

You have to know that:

$$\zeta(n)=\dfrac{2^n}{2^n-1}\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{(2k+1)^n}.$$

where $\zeta(\cdot)$ is the [Riemann zeta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function).

Comment: Shouldn't it be $\dfrac{2^n}{2^n-2}\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{(2k+1)^n}$?

Answer (score 2):

The polygamma functions are very smart to solve this kind of problem :

[image]